# What are SQL Cursors and how can I apply them to a simple database table?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, cursor

I'm trying to understand what cursors are and what use they are to me as a developer.

Please explain what they are and what benefit they bring over using say Entity Framework with an `IQueryable<T>` collection.

Also, imagine I have a table called Person. How would I apply cursors to this table?

```
create table Person
(
    ID int primary key,
    Name nvarchar,
    LastName nvarchar
);
```

Comment: In general cursors inside SQL Server database are a **Bad Idea™**.  You are using row-by-row logic and processes inside a system designed for set-based processing.  Any row-by-row logic is normally better handled in the calling application.

Comment: @JNK - Row-by-row processing is (as a rule) worse then set processing at any level. If you **have to** use row-by-row logic you will/might still be better off using it at the server level (in terms of total resources). Distributing processing to clients is indeed at *most* times desirable, but that is a general strategy decision and has nothing to do with cursors per se and also it depends on how the clients connect to the database and how they loop through records, what is it they need to do and what kind of locking they require.

Comment: @Unreason - Like most things it depends on the application, but I can't think of many scenarios where it is preferable to lock a table for all clients while a cursor runs as opposed to feeding data to an app and continuing to serve the rest of the clients.

Comment: @Unreason: Can you give a scenario where loacking a table for a single client is advisable?

Comment: @Serg - If you have a single client application, it makes sense (i.e. local database) as long as other jobs aren't accessing the same data.  I think what he was trying to say was, there is no "best" answer for 100% of scenarios.  I think most people will agree, though, that cursors in a shared SQL Server DB are best avoided if possible.

Comment: @JNK - example: slow links between client and server and relatively low number of records affected (or needed) you might be better off using server side cursors. Or if your server resources are cheaper then client resources (which would today be true only for some sort of thin clients or clients on embedded devices). But by all means I agree that, as a rule, every effort should be taken to avoid row-by-row processing first and if one must loop then it is (in general purpose scenarios) good to try to offload it to the client.

Comment: @Serg, JNK re locking - I was trying to say that client side and server side cursors might have different locking options. But not sure actually if that is true for ms sql server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cursors allow to process rows one by one. It's better to avoid using cursors as they are usually very slow compared to set based query operations. Here is some documentation about cursors to get you started: [DECLARE CURSOR (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx)

Comment: I figured out how to create Cursors following the link you gave. In the interest of completeness, can you edit your response with a code example of using cursors so when other people find this question they can easily learn from it?